# ANgular 5- BsModalRef throws NullInjector error

Tags: angular, systemjs, ngx-bootstrap

I am getting a NullInjector error for BsModalRef$$1 when I try to open modal.

My app.module.ts is as below

```
    import { ModalModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap';

    @NgModule({
     imports: [BrowserModule, RouterModule, ModalModule.forRoot()],
     ...
```

My system.config.js is like below

```
     paths: {
    // paths serve as alias

    'npm:': 'node_modules/'



},
// map tells the System loader where to look for things
map: {
    // our app is within the app folder
    'app': 'js',

    // angular bundles
    '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
    '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
    '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
    '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
    '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
    '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
    '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
    '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
    '@angular/upgrade': 'npm:@angular/upgrade/bundles/upgrade.umd.js',
    '@angular/upgrade/static': 'npm:@angular/upgrade/bundles/upgrade-static.umd.js',
    '@angular/common/http': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common-http.umd.js',
    'tslib': 'npm:tslib/tslib.js',

    // other libraries
    'rxjs':                      'npm:rxjs',
    'ngx-cookie-service':        'npm:ngx-cookie-service/cookie-service/cookie.service.js',
    'ts':                        'npm:plugin-typescript/lib',
    'typescript':                'npm:typescript/lib/typescript.js',
    'angular-scholarship-seed':     'npm:angular-scholarship-seed/bundles/angular-scholarship-seed.umd.js',
    'angular-dpa-seed':     'npm:angular-dpa-seed/bundles/angular-dpa-seed.umd.js',

    'ngx-bootstrap': 'npm:ngx-bootstrap/bundles/ngx-bootstrap.umd.js',
```

I have a component in a different web application which I am packaging using ng-packagr.

my component where I am calling BsModalRef is roughly as below

```
   import {ActivatedRoute, RouterModule, Router} from '@angular/router';
   import { BsModalService } from 'ngx-bootstrap';
    import { BsModalRef } from 'ngx-bootstrap';
   import { ModalContentComponent } from './athleticmodal/athletic.modal';
    import { TemplateRef} from '@angular/core';

    @Component({
selector: 'dummy-list',
    })
 export class DummyListComponent {

 modalRef: BsModalRef;

getAcademicTermsByDate(){
    this.modalRef = this.modalService.show(ModalContentComponent);
}
    constructor(private modalService: BsModalService) { }
}
```

I am packaging this and few other components using ng-packagr and published them to npm and referring from my main web application where my app.module.ts is there.

I added below external statement to ng-package.json

```
    {
"$schema": "./node_modules/ng-packagr/ng-package.schema.json",
"lib": {
    "entryFile": "public_api.ts",
     "externals": {
        "ngx-bootstrap": "ngx-bootstrap"
    }
}
 }
```

I tried a lot to make this work by trying other ways like changing the name in externals, importing BsModalRef from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal' and also like
        import { BsModalRef } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal/bs-modal-ref.service';

But nothing works. Could someone please help me out here.

Answer (score 0):

To start from, are you sure, that systemjs not loads code? I see `ModalModule.forRoot()`, and if ModalModule would be undefined or null, then you will get error `Cannot read property 'forRoot' of null`, not NullInjector error.

To make systemjs work, it needed to understand, how it works. Sometime, I had troubles like this, and looked up to jspm_packages folder contents. There what I found. For example, I do

```
import * as alina from "derivable-alina";
```

In systemjs config there is map:

```
 map: {
    "derivable-alina": "npm:derivable-alina@0.0.1",
```

Ok, go to `jspm_packages` folder, to `npm` subfolder, and see file, called `derivable-alina@0.0.1.js`. Open this file, and see next code:

```
 module.exports = require("npm:derivable-alina@0.0.1/dist/derivable-alina.js");
```

Ok, in npm folder, there is also folder, named `derivable-alina@0.0.1`, and it contains main library js-file. So, when I import "derivable-alina", systemjs

1. See to config's map, and resolve it to `npm:derivable-alina@0.0.1`
2. Loads `jspm_packages/npm/derivable-alina@0.0.1.js`, wich imports `npm:derivable-alina@0.0.1/dist/derivable-alina.js`
3. Loads `jspm_packages/npm/derivable-alina@0.0.1/dist/derivable-alina.js`

All this information was received by investigation by hand, and I can't say, that systemjs works like this everytime. But, you can try make your own investigation like this, and see, where the error occured.